# How to set the values of all the parameters of a tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a big tensorflow model (not using Keras). I know I can save and restore a tensorflow model, but what I need is different.

I want to store all the trainable parameters of the model in the memory, set all the trainable parameters to another set of values that I already have, and do predictions, and then restore the previously stored parameters back to the model.

Pseudo code:

```
original_variables = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
new_variables = original_variables - lr * gradients
set_trainable_variables(new_variables)
y = model.predict(X)
set_trainable_variables(original_variables)
```

Note that set_trainable_variables(vars) function is **only hypothetical**,

My question is: How to implement set_trainable_variables(vars)?

Comment: An response https://github.com/openai/supervised-reptile/blob/master/supervised_reptile/variables.py